# Proof of inequality involving binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, inequality, proof-writing, induction, binomial-coefficients

Proving things is not my forte. Stumbled upon following identity:

$$\binom{n+k+1}{k}>\sum_{i=1}^k \binom{\alpha_i}{i}$$ 
For

$\alpha_i<\alpha_j $ for $i<j$

$0\leq \alpha_i \leq n+k$

Also $\binom{a}{i}=0$ for $a<i$

Similar to the hockey-stick theorem. Not sure how to apply mathematical induction here.

**Edit:**

The right hand side of the inequality gets maximum value for $\alpha_1=n+1$ and $\alpha_k=n+k$. Therefore

$$\binom{n+k+1}{k} >  \sum_{i=1}^k \binom{n+i}{i} $$ 
comparing with hockey-stick theorem
\begin{eqnarray}
\binom{n+k+1}{k} &=&  \sum_{i=0}^k \binom{n+i}{i}  \\
&=&\sum_{i=1}^k \binom{n+i}{i} + 1 \\
&>& \sum_{i=1}^k \binom{n+i}{i}\\
&>& \sum_{i=1}^k \binom{\alpha_i}{i}
\end{eqnarray}
Q.E.D

Thanks to *CuddlyCuttlefish* for suggesting maximization of R.H.S of inequality.

Comment: Can you see how to maximize the right hand side?

Comment: Thanks. When $\alpha_k = n+k$ and $\alpha_i=n$. Alas, that I know because of calculations, not by way of logic.

Comment: (I think you mean $\alpha_i = n+i$, but that's exactly right) You can actually use the hockey stick theorem to solve this problem, using that fact

Comment: Post as an answer! @CuddlyCuttlefish